# Return array of arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Im building a function to return an array of arrays in php like this :

```
 function get_posts(){
        $ids = $post_userids = $names=$langs=$countrys=$post_images=$post_dates= $post_date_updateds = array();
        if ($countm = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id,post_userid,name,lang,country,post_image,post_date,post_date_updated FROM posts  ORDER BY `post_date` DESC ;")) {
            $countm->execute(); 
            $countm->store_result();
            $countm->bind_result($id,$post_userid,$name,$lang,$country,$post_image,$post_date,$post_date_updated); // get variables from result.
            $nr = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() ";
            $r = $mysqli->prepare($nr);
            $r->execute();
            $r->bind_result($no_posts);
            $r->fetch();
            $r->close();
     while ($l[] = $countm->fetch())
    {
      $ids[] = $id ;
      $post_userids[] = $post_userid ; 
      $names[] = $name ; 
      $langs[] = $lang ; 
      $countrys[] = $country ; 
      $post_images[] = $post_image ; 
      $post_dates[] = $post_date ; 
      $post_date_updateds[] = $post_date_updated ;   
     } ; 
       $countm->close();
     }else {printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);}
  return array('ids' => $ids,'post_userids' => $post_userids,'names' => $names,'langs' => $langs,'countrys' => $countrys,'post_images' => $post_images,'post_dates' => $post_dates,'post_date_updateds' => $post_date_updateds, 'no_posts' => $no_posts);
  }
```

Say i have two entries in my table , one with id 6 and other with id 7
and when i try to output

```
    $get_posts = get_posts();
    echo $get_posts['ids'][0]   //  it output  6
```

But when i set

```
   echo $get_posts['ids'][1]   // to get id 7 it output  error
```

And this also doesnt work.

```
    echo $get_posts['no_posts']   //  it output  error
```

I dont know if im doing something wrong or i missed something , or if there is better way to achieve this.

Edit :

```
   var_dump($get_posts)
```

gives

```
    array(2) { ["ids"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(6) } ["no_posts"]=> int(2) }
```

Comment: Please `var_dump($count_posts)` and add the output to your question. Also, your code seems incredibly hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: There is no `count_posts` function  defined anywhere in code shown. This all looks like a bad science experiment gone wrong

Comment: @charlietfl  , scuzzy  sorry , edited

Comment: @Scuzzy edited with var dumps

Comment: Why not having just `$post[$row['id']] = $row` and use `fetch_assoc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something simple like this:

```
function get_posts(){
    $posts = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT  id, post_userid, name, lang, country, post_image, post_date, post_date_updated FROM posts ORDER BY `post_date` DESC ;")) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $posts[$row['id']] = $row ;   
        }
    } else {
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: what about other values , names , lange ... ?

Comment: Please try and dump `$posts` all are inside, for `id` 6, `$post[6]` will be an associative array, the name is `$post[6]['name']`

Comment: you mean  var_dump($get_posts) ? , i couldnt dump posts , its inside function

Comment: I cannot understand you can dump inside function, by the way just dumping the result of the function is enough

Comment: do i have to give id is 6 ? i dont want give id , because its different every time . i want just fetch every thing ., i have also tried dump inside and didnt work

Comment: tried dump $posts . dump $posts['id']  nothing works

Comment: it gives this *(array(1) { [0]=> int(6) } )* but there is two ids

Comment: just dump the return of the function call, if it is not working dump `row` into the while loop to understand what is wrong. You can check the documentation here to have more example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php